# how to send native ftp words to one ftp server?

Tags: bash, ftp

if I connect to my ftp server using `ftp` command i'll have only a prompt waiting for me to enter one of the available commands listed using **help**, I am not newbie that much to believe those commands are wrappers of more sub-layered protocol ftp instructions such as 'MKD', 'SMNT', 'NLST', ([and more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands)).
I would like to know if it's possible to use native ftp commands using the `ftp` originally installed bash tool; And if not, is there some powerful tools to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `quote` (*send arbitrary ftp command*) to achieve that!

https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp